# Fetch mysql result in columns

Tags: php

I wish to divide my mysql fetched list in 2 columns. Eg.

```
A    |     D
B    |     E
C    |     F
```

I want to do it using table instead of < ul>< li>

```
<?php
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poet WHERE status='Publish' ORDER BY name ") or die(mysql_error());
        $total_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
        while ( $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ) {   ?>
    <tr>    
        <td class="navigation"><?php echo fetch_table_poet( $result["pid"], 1, 3); ?></td>
        <td class="navigation"><?php echo fetch_table_poet( $result["pid"], 1, 3); ?></td>
    </tr>   

<?php } ?>
```

I have this structure.

**NOTE** - I wish to perform my solutions using PHP not by anysort of jquery and javascript.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. It sounds like you want to make a table .. but yet ... you have a table. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poet WHERE status='Publish' ORDER BY name ") or die(mysql_error());
    $total_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    $resultSet = array();
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ) {
        $resultSet[] = $row;
    }

    $halfLength = count($resultSet) / 2;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $halfLength; $i++) {
?>
    <tr>    
        <td class="navigation"><?php echo fetch_table_poet( $resultSet[$i]["pid"], 1, 3); ?></td>
        <td class="navigation"><?php echo fetch_table_poet( $resultSet[$halfLength + $i]["pid"], 1, 3); ?></td>
    </tr>   

<?php } ?>
```